# Printing value of $0

Tags: ios, swift

I have a certain line of code which looks like so...

```
let myMessages = theObjects.filter { $0.myJid.user == user.JID.user }
```

Now I want to print the value of `$0.myJid.user`. How can I achieve that..?

Comment: Add the `return` keyword and you'll be able to insert extra statements (like a `print`) in any closure.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Cœur..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
let myMessages = theObjects.filter { (value) -> Bool in
    print(value.myJid)
    return value.myJid.user == user.JID.user
}
```

**Tip:** Naming your variable `user` seems like a bad idea since you already have a parameter with the same name for `JID`.

**Edit:** Seems i was wrong about not being able to print `$0`. You can do that just like in the regular closure. The only difference being you can omit the argument list and you need to add a `return`. To print using shorthand argument, check @Sateesh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53151805/7734643).

Comment: Thanks @Rakesha Shastri..It worked. Just one more concern..please bear with me..:)..Using $1 instead of $0 throws an error saying `Contextual closure type '(XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject) throws -> Bool' expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body`. Does this mean closures accept either true or false(i.e either one of these) and since I'm giving $1 which indicates a second value an error is thrown since only one value has to be there in the closure...?

Comment: There is no $1 in filter. The shorthand arguments exist to be used instead of the parameters that are defined for the closure. So unless the closure has 2 or more arguments (which is the case for `sort`), $1 doesn't exist.

Comment: ok @Rakesha Shastri. Thanks..So if $1 had to be valid, I presume there would have had to be  a value say x also along with `value` like so (value, x)...? and `theObjects.count` would also have had to have more than 1 value right..?

Comment: @user308123 it has nothing to do with the `theObjects`. Just take a look at the `sort` method. It has two arguments.

Comment: u mean sort takes 2 parameters and filter takes one parameter..?

Comment: @user308123 yes. You need to compare 2 things to sort them, right? So, it takes 2. You need just one to filter.

Comment: Ok @Rakesha Shastri .. so always..there's only a $0 when there's a filter and both $0 and $1 when there's sort..?

Comment: @user308123 There is $0 when the closure takes only one argument, $0 and $1 when it takes two, $0, $1, $2 when it takes three and so on...

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
let myMessages = theObjects.filter { print($0.myJid.user); return $0.myJid.user == user.JID.user }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sateesh...Have given an upvote...:)